# Building excel report with python

Tags: python, sql, excel, report, iteration

I am currently building an excel report with Python.  It will contain columns of job types beings applied for and rows of corresponding sources through which the job was applied.

I have a list of `Person` objects which contain the attributes `Name`, `Source` and `Job`.  My challenge currently is to elegantly iterate through these people and count the amount of people which applied to each job by source.

Currently I am obtaining a unique list of `Jobs` and a unique list of sources and iterating through them and matching them to people for which they match and increasing a counter and writing this count to an excel cell representing the correct job/source combination.

I have everything in a SQL database and am building `Person` objects from the corresponding tables so it's pretty unrestricted as to how I accomplish this but I just feel as though there is a more elegant solution to generate these counts than how I am accomplishing it currently.

All ideas are welcome. Here is my current solution below:

```
for job in jobs:
    for source in sources:
        for person in people:
            if person.job == job and person.source = source:
                count += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

tPerson:
ID
Name
Job_ID (fkey)
Source_ID (fkey)

tSource:
ID
Name

tJob:
ID
Name

Table structure noted above.  Desired output would be an excel spreadsheet with the distinct jobs lining the top row and the distinct sources listed down the first column.  For each job/source combination cell I need a count of the amount of people matching said combination.  Excel output seen below:

Job1  Job2
Source1   3        4
Source2   1        14
Source3   3        32

Any ideas on the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to generate all this from SQL. The query will obviously depend on your table definitions, but something like

```
select
    p.name,
    j.job,
    s.source,
    count(*)
from
    person p
        inner join
    job j
        on p.job = j.job
        inner join
    source s
        on p.source = s.source
group by
    p.name,
    j.job,
    s.source
order by
    p.name,
    j.job,
    s.source
```

If you have this query, you'll probably be able to put the results directly into Excel without using Python.

Comment: Laurence, although I do thoroughly appreciate the input, it doesn't quite return the exact results I needed.  It'd still require some processing in python which I'd prefer to do either entirely in SQL or entirely in Python.

Comment: @user1769667 You should be able to call the query from Python too, and the process the results.

Comment: Linking python with SQL and processing the results isn't of issue.  It seems to be peforming the required jobs/source count for each person which poses the problem.  The loop I provided accomplishes it but it isn't as attractive of a solution as I'd prefer.  Ideally I'd like to build a data structure which represents the excel sheet so I could write it whenever Id like without have to perform the counts each time I need them.

Comment: Why not post the table structure and desired output? Then it would be easier to help you with the code. I agree that this all sounds do-able from SQL directly.